# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.-error while writing to a file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

in my vb.net code im using streamwriter to write to a file that has been given as input to the form.

```
 Dim strContents As String
        Dim objReader As StreamReader
        Try

            objReader = New StreamReader("C:\test.txt")
            strContents = objReader.ReadToEnd()
            objReader.Close()

        Catch Ex As Exception

        End Try
        Dim Contents As String
        Dim bAns As Boolean = False
        Dim objWriter As StreamWriter
        Dim FileStream As System.IO.FileStream
        Try

            FileStream = New FileStream("C:\test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite)

            objWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\test.txt")
            objWriter.Write("fdgdfgdjkljljklg")
            objWriter.Close()
            bAns = True
        Catch Ex As Exception


        End Try
```

in some of the systems its working fine but in some other workstations its showing error that mentioned in the subject.

What restricts the access to the file here?
can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Some process has the file open. It may be your own code or it may be something else. Investigate, find out what process has it open & why. Random example: maybe the user has the file open in Word. Sorry, but it's impossible to be more helpful without more details.

Answer (score 2):

> What restricts the access to the file here?

The fact that you haven't disposed the stream and thus the process is locking the file. A `StreamWriter` is holding an unmanaged handle to the file. If you don't dispose this handle other threads/process cannot open the file.

I would recommend you to always wrap [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) resources in [`Using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) statement to ensure proper disposal (even if an exception is thrown inside the block):

```
Using filestream As New StreamWriter(Inifile, True, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
    ' ... use the filestream here to write to the file
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Unfortunately the code you provided also not working. If really any errors how its working in some systems and not in other?